# ¿Cómo agregar dos pantallas a la navegación de la aplicación React Native sin mostrarlas en la TabBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

Necesito que las pantallas de registro e inicio de sesión del usuario no se muestren en la TabBar de aplicación.
Es simple, intento tener dos tipos de interfaz de usuario, una para el modo de invitado y otra para cuando el usuario está autenticado. He creado una navegación para cada condicional, de forma que se muestra el TabBar correspondiente a cada estado de la aplicación, ya sea modo invitado o modo autenticado. También tengo un TabBarComponente para mostrar los Iconos de cada una de las Navegaciones.

El problema surge cuando quiero agregar las pantallas LoginScreeny RegisterScreenya que no puedo acceder a ellas.

Intenté crear un tercero Navigation(AuthNavigator) para administrar estas pantallas, y finalmente obtuve acceso, pero aparecen en la barra de pestañas, pero esto no puede ser, no se puede acceder a estas pantallas desde elTabBar

Necesito que estén en la navegación, pero que no se muestren en el TabBar.

En el TabBararchivo no se agregan estas pantallas, por lo que Iconno se muestra, pero se muestra el título

He intentado usar `options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}` , pero esto no tiene ningún efecto.

También `display = "none"` sin éxito.

He buscado soluciones en Google y no he encontrado nada.

Quiero mostrar mi sistema de navegación para guiarme en lo que estoy haciendo. equivocado y puede corregir mis errores.

```
    **--------- App.js ---------**

import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import GuestNavigator from './navigation/GuestNavigator'
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator'
const App = () => {
 
  const isUserAuthenticated = false; 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isUserAuthenticated ? (
        <AppNavigator />
      ) : (
        <GuestNavigator />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
export default App
```

---Esta es la navegación en modo INVITADO---

**---- GuestNavigator.JS -------**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabBar from '../components/TabBar';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const GuestNavigator = ({ handleLogin }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SampleNotas" component={SampleNotasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SampleCuras" component={SampleCurasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SamplePerfil" component={SamplePerfilScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Login"
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
        children={() => <LoginScreen handleLogin={handleLogin} />}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default GuestNavigator
```

--Esta es la navegación en modo AUTENTICADO --

**------ AppNavigator ---------**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabBar from '../components/TabBar';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Notas" component={NotasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="CrearNota" component={CrearNotaScreen} options={{ tabBarVisible: false }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Curas" component={CurasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Recordatorios" component={RecordatoriosScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditarProfileScreen} options={{ tabBarVisible: false }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default AppNavigator
```

Y también he creado un sistema de navegación solo para Iniciar Sesión y Registrarse

**------- AuthNavigator.js ----------**

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import LoginScreen from '../screens/AuthScreens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/AuthScreens/RegisterScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          component={RegisterScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Registro',
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
export default AuthNavigator
```

Por supuesto, si elimino LoginScrein de la navegación de GuestNavigator, obtengo un error:

**ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Login'? If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator. This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.**

Y también muestro el TabBar aunque muestra el icono y no se agregan estas pantallas.
**----- TabBar.js -----------**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const TabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation, isUserAuthenticated }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 60, backgroundColor: '#F3F9F5' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const isFocused = state.index === index;
        const color = isFocused ? '#08A438' : 'black';

        let iconName;
        if (!isUserAuthenticated) {
          // Iconos para el modo invitado
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = 'home';
          } else if (route.name === 'SampleNotas') {
            iconName = 'list';
          } else if (route.name === 'SampleCuras') {
            iconName = 'medkit';
          } else if (route.name === 'SamplePerfil') {
            iconName = 'person';
          }
        } else {
          // Iconos para el modo autenticado
          if (route.name === 'Notas') {
            iconName = 'notes';
          } else if (route.name === 'Curas') {
            iconName = 'medkit';
          } else if (route.name === 'Recordatorios') {
            iconName = 'alarm';
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = 'person';
          }
        }

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={onPress}
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
          >
            <Icon name={iconName} size={24} color={color} />
            <Text style={{ color }}>{route.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
export default TabBar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución estaba en incluir  la navegación de las pantallas de Invitado en `GuestNavigator`, y modificar  `<NavigationContainer>` de App

```
const AuthNavigator = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="GuestStack" component={GuestNavigator}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
   </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

y cambiar la forma en App

```
const isUserAuthenticated = false;
return (
   <NavigationContainer>
      {isAuth ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
   </NavigationContainer>
)
```